# Limits of infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What's the answer to the following problem? (along with solution)
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \sqrt{\{\sqrt{5-[rh]^2}-\sqrt{5-[(r-1)h]^2}\}^2 + h^2 }$$

I'm really out of my capacity to solve this problem but it's absolutely necessary to complete my understanding of certain topics.

Comment: This is not a *limit of infinite sum*, but an infinite sum of (trivial) limits.

Comment: yep, setting $h=0$ should do it. BTW prefer parenthesis eventually with a size modifier `\big` or `\bigg` rather than other types of brackets that can introduce confusion (with floor, round, frac ...)

Comment: But the answer should be $\frac{5\pi}{2}$. Its given where the topic is explained.

Comment: Then either you or someone else have "copied" the problem incorrectly.